# C program buffer overflow issue

Tags: c, linux, gcc, stack-overflow

I have a code for which the char array size is 8. If the gcc to compile the code with `-fno-stack-protector`, the `stack smashing detected` will only be detected after the string size is 12, such as `12345678901234567890`. If I use `-fstack-protector`, size 9 input will cause segmentation fault as shown below. May I know why the error only be detected at size 12 String input, not other numbers?

I did try different inputs with different char array sizes, the error will be detected when the overflow size is 11 to 13 (input size - char array size).

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

void readinput()
{
    char c, buf[8]; 
    int i;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) buf[i] = c;
    buf[i] = '\0';
    printf("string = [%s]\n", buf);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    readinput();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Undefined behaviour can do whatever it likes.  There is no rhyme or reason to what will happen.

Comment: A wire is rated with 100 kg strength. Why doesn't it snap at 101 kg tension?

Comment: Leak detection tools will only trigger on stack based variables when you get past the stack frame.  If you don't exceed the stack frame, and corrupt neighbouring variables, nothing will be reported.

Comment: You are allowed to write to c and i.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not check that `i` is less than the length of the array, so it has undefined behavior if user input exceeds 7 characters. Enabling compiler options for buffer overflow checking is not foolproof, not every offending access is tested. The C programmer is in charge, good practices are needed to try and avoid such problems.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readinput(void) {
    char buf[8]; 
    size_t i;
    int c;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';) {
        if (i + 1 < sizeof(buf))
            buf[i++] = c;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
    printf("string = [%s]\n", buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    readinput();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice improvements with `size_t i, int c, != EOF, i + 1 < sizeof(buf)`.